# Ruby: TMPDIR=/tmp cannot hold executables

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am trying to install **Ruby** on a remote server using **rbenv**.

However, when I run the command `rbenv install 2.7.2`, I get the error below:

> ruby-build: TMPDIR=/tmp cannot hold executables (partition possibly mounted with `noexec`)

I have **rbenv** and other dependencies for the Ruby programming language properly installed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a few research and trials, I was able to solve it.

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was that the **rbenv** installer needed a directory to store temporary files while it is downloading and installing ruby, however, the `/tmp` directory which is the default directory for storing temporary files wasn't accessible by my current user.

I tried to change permissions for the `/tmp` directory to allow it become accessible to my current user, however, I was unsuccessful.

All I had to do was to create a new `tmp` directory in the home directory of my user:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
```

Next, I opened the `.bashrc` file in the home directory of my user:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Next, I added the line below to the bottom of the file and saved:

```
export TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp"
```

Finally, I restarted my terminal or ran the command below to load the newly added paths into my current shell/terminal session:

```
exec "$SHELL"
```

Now, I could run the command `rbenv install 2.7.2` and it worked fine.

**Resources**: [TMPDIR=/tmp cannot hold executables (partition possibly mounted with `noexec`)](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/703#issuecomment-183067934)

Comment: `~tmp` is the *home directory of user `tmp`* but `~/tmp` is `tmp` in your home directory.

Comment: You might also create a `~/tmp` dir and then try using `env TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp" rbenv install 2.7.2` and you wouldn't need to change any shell start up files.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037187), you don't need to create a new tmp folder. Only adding to the path should work as well.